# Why does not compiler auto detect readonly structs?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

C# 7.2 introduced the concept of [readonly structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types). So basically we can now use the keyword `readonly struct` on any immutable struct whatsoever. This reduces performance overhead as these structs can now be passed by reference with the new `in` keyword and `ref return`.

Why does not C# compiler make *all* of the immutable structs `readonly` automatically and then use those `ref` language features without asking? I mean they are immutable anyway, what could go wrong if you passed them by reference everywhere?

Comment: can you give your example of immutable struct which should get auto-detected by the compiler ?

Comment: @C.Dhruv pretty much any struct with only `get` properties and `readonly` fields.

Comment: `in` represents a calling-convention change. Since .NET code can be precompiled, changing the calling convention would be a breaking change. If they'd changed the language semantics to apply `readonly` automatically to immutable structs and then applied `in` to any call site where such structs were used, you could have a calling-convention mismatch when new code calls old code or vice a versa. I can't tell you why the C# language team decided to implement the feature this way, but I can certainly see why they _might_ have.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't quite understand how this would be a breaking change - could you please introduce an example of a `readonly struct` that would have different behaviours with and without the `in` keyword applied to it? That is pretty much what the question is about so you could really post it as an answer.

Comment: Passing a variable by ref means it can be used as both an input to a method and an output.The issue is the compiler cannot determine if the memory for the object has been allocated.When an object is marked as ref the calling method must allocate the memory for the object.The calling method cannot allocate the memory because the object is on the calling stack and the calling stack becomes invalid once the method is terminated.To make sure the object is pre-allocated before calling a method structure were assigned readonly. When objects are allocated by calling mehtods run time errors can occur.

Comment: @bashis suppose you have legacy method which accepts some immutable struct as parameter. This method expects that contents of this struct are on stack (sometimes in register, doesn't matter) when method is called. However, with "in" - not struct contents are passed to the method, but pointer to its location. So this just will not work without recompilation of this legacy method.

Comment: Was it not already a recommended coding practice to have ONLY immutable structs? If the struct needs to change, then it should be a class.

Comment: @Krythic it was recommended but not mandatory: mutable structs are supported on the language level and you have to deal with them when developing a compiler.

Comment: @Evk makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @Krythic even some built-in structs are mutable. For example, System.ValueTuple is a struct with mutable public fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is only meant as a possible perf optimization for *large* structures.  The kind you may end up with when replacing a class with a struct.  Small structs perform best when they are passed by value, the struct members can then be passed through CPU registers with no worry of having to propagate the changes back to the caller.  Passing by reference requires an extra indirection on each member access, that nullifies one advantage of a struct.

Passing a large struct by value incurs the cost of copying the struct value at method entry and exit.  The jitter always assumes that member access needs to be fast, even if infrequent member access would make passing by reference more optimal.  Technically the optimizer could figure out what would be the best choice, but that kind of flow analysis is quite hard to do correctly, optimizers always skirt the Halting Problem.  And these language changes had to be made without requiring a change in the CLR and the jitter.

So blindly applying `in` (or ref) is not a good idea, you have to trade the cost of the extra indirection against the copying.  Realistically, this is something you contemplate when a profiler showed you that a particular method call is a bottleneck.  As the C# team did, I think these changes were inspired by making Roslyn faster.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why would it be hard for the compiler to get if the struct is big enough or not to gain the advantage of passing it by ref automatically?

Comment: Lots of web pages about the Halting Problem, worth a read.  Imagine the struct member being used inside a loop that is only occasionally entered, the optimizer would have to predict how often it is entered, how frequently it loops and make that decision after it figured out if the access can be hoisted out of the loop to make the correct choice.  Even a C compiler whose optimizer has lots of time to execute only does this in select cases.

Comment: Why wouldn't it always be faster to pass anything bigger than size of the pointer by reference and anything smaller or equal by value?

Comment: Because, as noted, accessing the structure members requires an extra indirection when it is passed by reference.  It avoids dereferencing a pointer.  It depends, the processor's prefetcher might be able to do a decent job and avoid the 3 cycle L1 cache latency.  Profiling is important.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense now. Thank you.